# How to print variable from controller to layout?

Tags: twig, drupal-8

Controller :

```
public function content() {    
      return array(
        '#theme' => 'test',
        '#varTest' => 'toto'
      );
  }
```

module theme hook :

```
function test_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'test' => [
      'variables' => ['varTest' => 'defaultVal']
    ]
  ];
}
```

Layout html.html.twig :

```
  <html>
      <head>
        {{ varTest }}
```

If I print variable in the layout varTest is null. If I  print variable in the template "test" varTest = 'toto'

Why Layout does not print 'toto' or 'defaultVal' ?

Comment: You try to render variable in an incorrect template file. You registered test_theme so your file should be test.html.twig instead html.html.twig

Comment: varTest is displayed in the template test.html.twig that inherits html.html.twig but this layout should be able to display as well (as symfony real framework)... but no